# How to call rest service which is integrated with single sign on?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth, single-sign-on

I have a web site which integrated with my company Single Sign On(SAML 2.0 protocol).  The site also have API defined. Now I am trying to access the API from C# console application.

How my console application can authenticate and broker between SSO server and web api ?

Comment: You have to provide more details on what actual SSO protocol is used. While most protocols suport active agents, details vary from protocol to protocol.

Comment: SSO is using SAML.

Comment: Which one, the 1.1 or 2.0?

Comment: It is using SAML 2.0.

Comment: There are two possible approaches. You either use an active flow to carry saml tokens between the client and the server or you use any other tokens, could even be forms auth cookies, from client, assuming the client first claims the token somehow by using the passive flow.